# Abort async function which contains setInterval with a eventcall

Tags: javascript, async-await, setinterval, addeventlistener

Firt of all: i do not master the async-await and promises syntax. So I'M very sorry if my snippet code is a piece of sh...

I want to call a function (launchTestAtFrequency) which launch an interval and waiting for user event to stop this interval, and again launch the launchTestAtFrequency function.

I read about Promise and Async-Await and tried it by myself. But it's like "whaaaat????"

This application needs to be lightfull so I can't user jQuery or other JS libraries.

```
var oscillator;
var panner;
var volume;
var leftOrRight; // 0 = left ; 1 = right;
var interval;
var user_hearing; // set to 1 when user is hearing something

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { if(e.ctrlKey) { CTRL_Parse(e) }})

function CTRL_Parse(e) { // Filter eventHandler to parse if it's left or right CTRL which is pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.location == 1) left_hearing();
    else if(e.location == 2) right_hearing();
}

function left_hearing() { // What to do when user say "i'm hearing on my right ear"
    user_hearing = 1;
}

function right_hearing() { // What to do when user say "i'm hearing on my right ear"
    user_hearing = 1;
}

async function launchTestAtFrequency(leftOrRight, frequency = 440) {
    oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
    (leftOrRight) ? panner.setPosition(+3, 0, 0) : panner.setPosition(-3, 0, 0); // Set panner to left or right ear
    return await volumeUp(); // Return the volume for measuring the hearing evaluation
}

async function volumeUp () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {                // Volume up the sound from 0 to 0.5
        interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (volume.gain.value >= 0.5 || user_hearing) { // Stop when user is hearing something or if volume >= 0.5 (= fail)
            clearInterval(interval);
            return volume.gain.value;
        } else {
            volume.gain.value += .005;
        }
    }, 250);
}

async function launchTestAtFrequency(leftOrRight, frequency = 440) { // Just intializing the oscillator/panner then start volumeUp()
        oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
        (leftOrRight) ? panner.setPosition(+3, 0, 0) : panner.setPosition(-3, 0, 0);
        return await volumeUp(); // Need to resolve volumeUp before continue to the next ear
}

function callPreview() {
    var reverse = (leftOrRight) ? 0 : 1;
    launchTestAtFrequency(leftOrRight).then(launchTestAtFrequency(reverse)); // Need to be called twice, once with leftOrRight at 0 or 1, then reverse (1 or 0)
}
```

I expect launchTestAtFrequency() to be launch a first time, wait for volumeUp() to be resolve when user is pressing CTRL, then launch launchTestAtFrequency() a second time to test the other ear and wait for volumeUp() to be resolve when user is pressing CTRL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the crucial connection between `await` and the thing awaited: it needs to be a promise.

If it's not a promise, it's converted to one implicitly (one that's instantly resolved). That's what's happening in your case, which is why no waiting is happening.

Note also that it's the awaiting function (`launchTestAtFrequency()`) that needs to be async, not the function that returns the value being awaited (`volumeUp()`).

A simplified version of your code might look like this:

```
async function launchTestAtFrequency() {
    return await volumeUp(); //<-- need to ensure volumeUp() returns a promise
}

function volumeUp() {
    return new Promise(resolve => { //<-- return promise to await
        if (1 || 2)
            resolve();
    });
}
```

Additionally, your code contains errors that would have been picked up by the console. You have two nested intervals, for example (which is a pattern I've never seen and can't imagine being useful for anything), but the inner one is missing its second argument and closing braces.

Comment: OK! Got it! There are so many resources over the web, sometimes you just need someone to say "well, it's just like that...". The code's errors is due to copy/simplify/paste, to clarify my ask. My code works fine, except one things. The launchTestAtFrequency is called only one time, why??
` async function launchTestAtFrequency(leftOrRight) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   await volumeUp();
  });
 }
 function callPreview() {
  await launchTestAtFrequency(leftOrRight).then( async function() { await launchTestAtFrequency(reverse) });
 }`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that without digging in detail into your specific use case, but hopefully I've given you a grounding in how async/await works.

Comment: Well, I understand, and after all I'm supposing the problem is coming from elsewhere because  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RomainMazB/26y0etcp/12/) works. That prove I got it! Thanks for you help.